# How to access to the properties of List<T>, where T is a different object every time

Tags: c#

How can I access to the properties of `List<T>`,where T every time is another type of object, Student, Product, etc.? The problem is that at the compile time C# can't recognize the properties which are included in the T. As you can see (as it's commented in the code) I make `foreach`, where after that when I try `itemList`, the properties from the object aren't shown.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentLinq {

    public class Student {
        public int Id {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Admin {
        public string Name {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Generic {
        public void Print<T>(List<T> list) {
            foreach(var itemList in list) {
                if (list is List<Student>) {
                    Console.WriteLine(itemList);
                }
                //How can I print the properties from the product class and student 
            }
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var studentsList = new List<Student>();
            studentsList.Add(new Student {
                Id = 2
            });

            var productList = new List<Product>();
            productList.Add(new Product {
                Price = 40
            });

            var generic = new Generic();

            generic.Print<Student>(studentsList);
            generic.Print<Product>(productList);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know if you solved this? And which of the answers given below helped you?

Comment: All of them were very good answers.Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

### What generics are for

The idea behind generics is that they do the *same thing* to everything you pass to it. For example, it is possible to write a generic function to take the count of any type of list, because all lists can be counted.

```
int GetCount<T>(List<T> source)
{
    return source.Count();
}
```

### What generics are not for

If you have to do *different things* to different types, generics is not the right answer. The typical way to deal with it is with different functions, each of which accepts the type that matches its logic. The functions can have the same name if you want (this is known as [method overloading](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/method-oveloading-and-overriding-C-Sharp/)).

```
void Print(List<Student> list)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Id);
    }
}

void Print(List<Admin> list)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Name);
    }
}
```

### How to make a method generic for more than one class

If you happen to discover that some of your objects have properties in common, you can give them a common interface that contains the common property or properties:

```
interface IHasName
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Admin : IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Student: IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### How to make your properties appear

Once you have the common interface, you can write a generic method with a [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), and your properties will suddenly be available to you. Only those properties that are guaranteed to exist by the type constraint will be available; this makes the generic method type-safe.

```
public void Print<T>(List<T> source) where T : IHasName
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Name);
    }
}
```

### Another way to handle the problem

Another way to deal with this sort of problem is to provide a generic callback.

```
void Print<T>(List<T> source, Func<T,string> callback)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", callback(item));
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var list = new List<Student>();
Print(list, item => item.Id.ToString());

var list2 = new List<Admin>();
Print(list2, item => item.Name);
```

This works because the logic that accesses the properties is contained in your callback and not in the generic method, thus sidestepping the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your objects have nothing in common and you do not want to use `Polymorphism` then by all means use `System.Reflection`:

```
public void Print<T>(List<T> list)
{
    foreach (var itemList in list)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var values = properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(itemList));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
    }
}
```

You do not need to define the method as `generic` anymore.

Comment: If the source is `List<T>` you can't pass it as `List<object>`.

Comment: I assumed he could choose the signature of the method and just pointed out that it need not be generic anymore if using reflection.

Comment: You just made it much harder by not being generic. Two things - your code doesn't compile, but it's a minor issue - and rather than `itemList.GetType()` it might be worth doing `typeof(T)` so that you ensure a consistent output as the real type might be derived from `T`.

Comment: You are right indeed.`typeof` is the way to go if it is `generic`

Comment: You still have a syntax error. Did you test your code before posting?

Answer (score 0):

John Wu's answer provides some great advice - In this case it's worth noting that you don't need to use generics to do exactly what you want, Just use the non-generic interface and interact with them as object instances :

```
    static void Print(IEnumerable data)
    {

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case String str:
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest overwriting the `ToString()`-Method in your classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id?.ToString();
    }
}

public class Admin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    } 
}

public class Generic
{
    public void Print<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item); // Implicitly calls ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter could elaborate on the problem with my answer. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Apologies did not see your override to `ToString()` I have revoked downvote. However, there is one problem though in this approach, it does not give an individual access to properties if there are multiple properties in the class. We will have to resort to some string manipulations.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Thank you. You are correct. But as the question is asked, it can not be deferred what exactly should be output. Therefore I'd argue, that all 3 answers have some merit, depending on what the OP wants exactly

Comment: _"it can not be deferred [sic] what exactly should be output"_ -- frankly, given that's the case, I'd argue that none of the three answers have merit, because the question should not be answered until it _can_ be inferred what exactly should be the output.

Answer (score -1):

You can go with this option if your list of generic classes is limited. I would recommend @Bercovici Adrian's answer over this one. Anyways, I will give another way of doing it.

You can use the c# `as` operator to convert the list into its non-generic member after finding out its correct type using `if`

```
public class Generic
    {
        public void Print<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            if(list is List<Student>)
            {
                var studentList = list as List<Student>;
                foreach (var itemList in studentList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(itemList.Id);
                }
            }
            else if(list is List<Product>)
            {
                var productList = list as List<Product>;
                foreach(var itemList in productList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(itemList.Price);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP is using `Student` and `Product` as examples; they want a general purpose approach.